# While running the selenium from jenkins, it does not open the automated browser instead it runs in the background why?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jenkins, continuous-integration, cicd

While running the selenium from jenkins, it does not open the automated browser instead it runs in the background why?

I tried to run selenium from CI/CD jenkins and while running, the jenkins does not open the webdriver instead it run in the background and show the results only.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.